# maskededitvalidator validationgroup is set, still not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, validationgroup, maskededitvalidator

I have 2 textbox which accept time from users, to which I have set the Maskededitextender and maskededitvalidator as follows:

textbox 1:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtInTime" Text ="00:00" CssClass="txtbox" MaxLength="5" 
                                        Width="43px" runat="server" ValidationGroup="date" 
                                       ></asp:TextBox>



                     <cc1:MaskedEditExtender ID="MaskedEditExtender2" runat="server"  TargetControlID="txtInTime"
                        Mask="99:99" MessageValidatorTip="true" MaskType="Time" InputDirection="RightToLeft"
                        ErrorTooltipEnabled="True" />                      

                    <cc1:MaskedEditValidator ID="MaskedEditValidator2"  runat="server" ControlExtender="MaskedEditExtender2"
                        ControlToValidate="txtInTime"  MaximumValue="23:59" MinimumValue="00:00"
                       MaximumValueMessage="23:59"  ValidationGroup="date"
                        InvalidValueBlurredMessage="Time Invalid"
                        MinimumValueMessage="Time must be greater than 00:00:00"  ForeColor ="Red" 
                        ToolTip="Enter time between 00:00 to 23:59">
                        </cc1:MaskedEditValidator>
```

textbox 2:

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtOutTime" Text ="00:00" CssClass="txtbox" MaxLength="5" 
                                        Width="43px" runat="server" ValidationGroup="date" 
                                       ></asp:TextBox>



                     <cc1:MaskedEditExtender ID="MaskedEditExtender3" runat="server"  TargetControlID="txtOutTime"
                        Mask="99:99" MessageValidatorTip="true" MaskType="Time" InputDirection="RightToLeft"
                        ErrorTooltipEnabled="True" />                      

                    <cc1:MaskedEditValidator ID="MaskedEditValidator1"  runat="server" ControlExtender="MaskedEditExtender3"
                        ControlToValidate="txtOutTime"  MaximumValue="23:59" MinimumValue="00:00"
                       MaximumValueMessage="23:59" ValidationGroup="date"
                        InvalidValueBlurredMessage="Time Invalid"
                        MinimumValueMessage="Time must be grater than 00:00:00"  ForeColor ="Red" 
                        ToolTip="Enter time between 00:00 to 23:59">
                        </cc1:MaskedEditValidator>
```

then I have a button on whose click a process happens, but if the maskededitvalidator displays invalid data, the button's code behind must not execute. But in my case the code behind executes despite the maskededitvalidator displaying invalid data. I have set the validation group of all the concerned controls, yet the issue.

Button:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnLoadEmployees"  ValidationGroup="date" CssClass="button" runat="server" Text="Load Employees" OnClick="btnLoadEmployees_Click"/>
```

Please guys, help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    Please Enter Time:
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtBoxTime" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <ajax:MaskedEditExtender ID="MaskedEditExtender3" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtBoxTime"
    Mask="99:99:99" MaskType="Time" MessageValidatorTip="true" InputDirection="RightToLeft" >
    </ajax:MaskedEditExtender>
    <ajax:MaskedEditValidator ID="MaskedEditValidator3" runat="server" ControlExtender="MaskedEditExtender3"
     ControlToValidate="txtBoxTime" IsValidEmpty="false" MaximumValue="23:59:59" MinimumValue="00:00:00"
     EmptyValueMessage="Please enter time"
     MaximumValueMessage="Please enter time less than 23:59:59" MinimumValueMessage="Please enter time greater than 00:00:00" >
    </ajax:MaskedEditValidator>
```

Ref from : http://www.devasp.net/net/articles/display/1373.html

dont forget to put validation Groups

Comment: Thanks @LS206. I found a workaround. I checked the Page.Isvalid in Javascript and displayed an alert to rectify the Invalid data. Thanka a lot for your help though.

Comment: u can check  Page.Isvalid  at server side also.